# Delphi Anchor and Form.HorizontalScrollbar.Range Panel Anchor akRight ignores HorizontalScrollbar.Range

Tags: forms, delphi

I have here a very simple form for demonstration purposes . On Form Show I only do this :

```
  Form1.HorzScrollBar.Range:=1200;
```

My Problem is if I resize the Form and the Formsize becomes less then 1200 , the Panel akRight anchor is not taking into account Actual Form size , instead it seems to look at the Visible Form Size...

See Screenshot[image]

I am probably doing here something wrong , can someone enlighten me.

Comment: I want the form to have a minimum Width of 1200 . Otherwise some controls are no longer visible ( I am talking  about a more complex form ) . So I am trying to make  my form show a scrollbar if its width is less then 1200 . I would thus like to have the Panel have the width of the Form and not that of the ClientRect ...

Comment: Just guessing since you did not really say anything about this, but if, on the other hand you want the panel to *grow* beyond 1200 when the form is stretched over 1200, but that the panel never shrinks below 1200, you can actually 1) set the `akRight` anchor on the panel and 2) additionally set the `Constraint.MinWidth` property to 1200. Constraint is stronger than the anchor.

Comment: This is the answer :) Thank you! I did not think about this... Panel Constraint.MinWidth solves my problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the panel growing with the form beyond 1200, but prevent the panel from shrinking below 1200, you can set for the panel:

- Set the `akRight` anchor (in addition to `akLeft`)
- Set the `Constraint.MinWidth = 1200`